# Section Header Adapter for Recyclerview

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

I have a list Items and each item has time associated with it.What I want to do is, showing items in different section and date is the section header.(Items which has same date has to be shown under one section).Just  like Google's Inbox app. I have tried to implement this using a HashMap> where key is date like 07/11/2015 and value is arraylist of items which belongs to that date. But its very slow and producing jerky experience on scrolling of list. Items may get add to list dynamically to any section. Sorry I can't post the code.

Thanks

Comment: look at this https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/4c189fb1124df4556058

Comment: I don't think above link will solve the issue. Because how will adapter that we find in the above link support dynamic insertion of items?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe ExpandableListView can help you, check this link for detail http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: Ok @ResolutioN I'll check